# Check viewer to open file in Android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-package-managers

In android/Hybrid app, I am using following code to check "Is viewer to open file is installed on device or not"

```
private boolean detectFileViewer(String fileExt) throws InterruptedException,
JSONException {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType( MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt));
        if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On Android Lollipop, if only default PDF viewer i.e. "Drive PDF Viewer" is present above code is returning false as

```
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
```

is returning empty array.
Also above code is working fine on previous versions of Android.

Tested on nexus 4 and nexus 5 with Android Lollipop.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying ,you are saying check  is there application for open the file ?

Comment: Yes, I mean is there an application installed to open particular file type for example pdf, doc, zip, etc.
And we are passing file type as attribute to function "fileExt"

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void openFile(final Context context, File url, final Activity activity) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    File file = url;
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    } else {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "There isn't any program open this file!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

do you wanna like that ? or just check it?

Comment: I need to check and open file if viewer is present.
In your suggestion what will happen if user didn't have pdf viewer installed on device or disabled it?